# Java Unit Test for models

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Imagine an example class:

```
public class Debit extends AbstractDebit {

@Column(name = "ID_PESSOAS", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private Long idContribuinte;

...more fields here
```

Is necessary a unit test of this class?

Comment: No. There is nothing to test. If you want to make sure all your annotations work like they should, you should look into Integration tests, instead of unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a valid case for unit tests; I take it that the name and the other properties is important for your application to work as expected, and when do you want to spot a breaking change (for e.g. if a developer changes that name)? I say as early as possible. And this kind of code is easy to unit test, of course you can test this during integration testing as well - but finding out that a test fails due to a column name change will most likely not be straight forward.

Comment: Thanks, Jocke. My reputation not permit a vote for you, sorry.

Comment: You are welcome. I see, but you should be able to accept is as an answer.